# Plotting 3D surface in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, surface

Although there are several sources on how to plot 3D surfaces with XYZ format. I have a CSV file from a scanning laser that provides no coordinate information on X and Y, just Z coordinates of a rectangular grid.

The file is 800 x 1600 with just z coordinates. Excel can plot it very easily with surface plot, but is limited by size.

How can I approach this problem?

[Screenshot of data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSemc.png)

Comment: This is a good start, it's pretty easy to follow, and I've created a nice 3D surface plot using this as a base. [link](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) You'll also probably need to use numpy's `meshgrid` Just use the indices of the array as your x and y values

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create arrays of the `X` and `Y` coordinates. We can do this with [`numpy.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html). In the example below, I set the cell size to 1., but you can easily scale that by changing the `cellsize` variable.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

# Create x, y coords
nx, ny = 800, 1600
cellsize = 1.
x = np.arange(0., float(nx), 1.) * cellsize
y = np.arange(0., float(ny), 1.) * cellsize
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# dummy data
Z = (X**2 + Y**2) / 1e6

# Create matplotlib Figure and Axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

print X.shape, Y.shape, Z.shape

# Plot the surface
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and a reply from @tmdavison turn me on in the right direction. But this answer unclear in the part of retrieving data from the CSV file.

Here is my solution.

```py
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

def csv_3d(file_name):
    """Draw content of csv file with matplotlib 3D like MS Excel."""
    data = [
      [float(i.replace(',', '.')) for i in row]
      for row in csv.reader(open(file_name), delimiter=';')
    ]
    # matplotlib/numpy magic
    x_arr, y_arr = numpy.meshgrid(
      numpy.arange(0.0, float(len(data[0])), 1.0),  # x: number of columns in csv
      numpy.arange(0.0, float(len(data)), 1.0),  # y: number of rows in csv
    )
    z_arr = numpy.array(data)  # transform csv data into 2D values numpy array

    plt.figure(num=file_name)
    axes = plt.axes(projection="3d")
    axes.plot_surface(x_arr, y_arr, z_arr)
    plt.show()

csv_3d('my.csv')
```